# JavaScript How do I overcome asynchronousness of JavaScript if a promise have already been used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

It's not the first time I've had this problem but I always managed to find a workaround, which is fine I guess, but now I wanted to get some understanding on how I can improve. So, in my example I have a list of courses, and I need to calculate an average rating for each of them:

```
var vm = this;

course.averageRating = vm.getAverageRating(course.id);
```

Now, what does not work:

```
vm.getAverageRating = function (courseId) {
       let sum = 0, courses = [];
       courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(function(results){
            courses = results;
        });

       courses.forEach(function (course) {
            if(course && course.feedback_rating) {
                sum += course.feedback_rating;
            }
       });
       return courses.length > 0 ? sum / courses.length : null;
};
```

Obviously, what happens is that **courses.forEach** fires before the application actually downloads the list of userCourses from the server and the function always returns **null**.

My workaround is as follows:

```
vm.averageRatings = {};

vm.getAverageRating = function (courseId) {
  let sum = 0, courses = [];
  courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(function(results){
       courses = results;

       courses.forEach(function (course) {
            if(course && course.feedback_rating) {
                sum += course.feedback_rating;
            }
       });

       vm.averageRatings[courseId] = courses.length > 0 ? sum/courses.length : null;
  });
};
```

I believe this is not the best method to go about this problem. I cannot use a return statement inside **then** in my first example, and I also cannot use a promise on a promise. How would you solve this problem if you were in my place?

Comment: "I cannot use a promise on a promise"…? Well, you *could*; but you really just need to `return` the promise you already have.

Comment: I think the "workaround" you came up with is actually (one of) the right way(s) to do. Not the most elegant, but right.

Comment: Same problem, I want more clean code result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the promise is fine, but you should

- return the promise for the value instead of writing to some pre-determined object
- simplify your code, specifically the variable declarations

```
function getAverageRating(courseId) {
  return courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(function(courses) {
//^^^^^^                                                ^^^^^^^
    let sum = 0;
    for (const course of courses)
      sum += course && course.feedback_rating || 0;
    return courses.length > 0 ? sum/courses.length : null;
  });
};

getAverageRating(course.id).then(avg => {
  course.averageRating = avg;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the best solution. Although return courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback.... returns an object instead of a number (something like d.$$state.value to get the average value). Do you know if there's a way to fix it besides getting the value through a few layers in the object?

Comment: It returns a promise, which you have to await using `.then()`. Don't peek into its private properties.

Answer (score 1):

getAverageRating *is* asynchronous. However you may wanna cache the results:

```
 var cache = {};   
 vm.getAverageRating = function (courseId) {

  return cache[courseId] || 
   (cache[courseId] = courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId)
     .then(function(courses){
        return (
         courses.reduce((sum,course)=>sum + (course.feedback_rating || 0),0)
         / courses.length) || null;
    })
  );      
};
```

Usable like this:

```
vm.getAverageRating(1).then( res => console.log(res));
vm.getAverageRating(1).then( res => console.log(res));
```

Both will refer to the same promise, so they will be resolved at the same time with the same result. There are not two requests but just one.

Answer (score 1):

to answer the question

> How would you solve this problem if you were in my place?

A combination of your two approaches would be

```
vm.getAverageRating = function (courseId) {
 return courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(courses => courses.length > 0 ? (courses.map(course => (course && course.feedback_rating) ? course.feedback_rating : 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b))/courses.length : null);
};
```

how to use:

```
vm.getAverageRating("someID").then(result => {
    // result is the result you want
});
```

> the first block of code is simply, in case ES2015+ is unfamiliar

```
vm.getAverageRating = function (courseId) {
    return courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(function (courses) {
        return courses.length > 0 ? courses.map(function (course) {
            return (course && course.feedback_rating) ? course.feedback_rating : 0;
        }).reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }) / courses.length : null;
    });
};
```

Comment: Youre missing a return :/

Comment: Yes. I thought i added it. Which was the reason for my comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using babel or Node 8.x you can use [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

This would simplify your function to something like this:

```
vm.getAverageRating = async function (courseId) {
       let sum = 0, courses = [];
       await courseContext.getUserCourseFeedback(courseId).then(function(results){
            courses = results;
        });

       courses.forEach(function (course) {
            if(course && course.feedback_rating) {
                sum += course.feedback_rating;
            }
       });
       return courses.length > 0 ? sum / courses.length : null;
};
```

Comment: That's not really a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

`vm.getAverageRating()` relies on the results of an asynchronous operation hence it can return nothing to the synchronous timeline. What you do is basically right but would be better if `vm.getAverageRating()` returns a promise instead. So I would mimic your code as follows;

```js
function getAverageRating(n){
  return Promise.resolve(Array.from({length: n})
                              .map(_ => 25+Math.floor(76*Math.random()))) // get course ratings
                .then(function(crs){
                        var sum = crs.reduce((p,c) => p+c),
                            avg = crs.length ? sum / crs.length : null;
                        return [crs,avg];
                      });
}
getAverageRating(10).then(([crs,avg]) => console.log("course ratings are: ", crs, "average is: ", avg));
```